# Cells of the row stack vertically on using flexbox style in all cells of the table

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox inside Row cells in order to display the two items present inside the cell at two extreme ends of the cell. One item inside is a text and other is a color dot/square created using a span element. As long as it is used for only one cell of the row, the display is as expected but as soon as the same style is applied for other cells in the row, they start getting lined up one over the other.

[This is how it appears with flexbox style added to only one cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnsIZ.png)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sandeep10au/pen/XWdRvLb

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: #192038;
}

.table tr th {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.flexBox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dotRed {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ff3333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dotAmber {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ffd480;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dotGreen {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #5cd65c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: center;
}

.squareRed {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ff3333;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.squareAmber {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ffd480;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.squareGreen {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #5cd65c;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="flexBox">
        West Europe
        <span class="squareGreen" />
      </th>
      <th>
        North Europe
        <span class="squareRed" />
      </th>
      <th>
        East Europe
        <span class="squareAmber" />
      </th>
      <th>
        East US-2
        <span class="squareGreen" />
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      IoT Hub
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      IoT Hub
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      IoT Hub
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      IoT Hub
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      TimeSeries Insights
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      TimeSeries Insights
      <span class="dotRed" />
    </td>
    <td>
      TimeSeries Insights
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      TimeSeries Insights
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Service Bus
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Service Bus
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Service Bus
      <span class="dotAmber" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Service Bus
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[This is when the flexbox style is added to all cells in the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7V8GK.png)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/sandeep10au/pen/mdPmNNp

```css
.table {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      color: #192038;
    }    

.table tr th{
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 2rem;
    }

.flexBox{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dotRed {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ff3333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dotAmber {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ffd480;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dotGreen {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #5cd65c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: center;
}

.squareRed {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ff3333;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.squareAmber {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ffd480;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.squareGreen {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #5cd65c;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="flexBox">
                West Europe
                <span class="squareGreen"/>
            </th>
            <th class="flexBox">
                North Europe
                <span class="squareRed"/>
            </th>
            <th class="flexBox">
                East Europe
                <span class="squareAmber"/>
            </th>
            <th class="flexBox">
                East US-2
                <span class="squareGreen"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            IoT Hub
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            IoT Hub
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            IoT Hub
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            IoT Hub
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            TimeSeries Insights
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            TimeSeries Insights
            <span class="dotRed"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            TimeSeries Insights
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            TimeSeries Insights
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Service Bus
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            Service Bus
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            Service Bus
            <span class="dotAmber"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            Service Bus
            <span class="dotGreen"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have to use the flexbox style in all the cells of the table(with the table appearing in proper tabular for). Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this, you need to have table rows as flexbox as well:

```
.table tr { display:flex; flex-direction:row; width:100%; }
.table tr th,
.table tr td { flex: 1; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a div inside th and it works..

```css
.table {
      width: 100%;
      margin-top: 1rem;
      color: #192038;
    }    

.table tr th{
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        font-size: 1rem;
        line-height: 2rem;
    }

.flexBox{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.dotRed {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ff3333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dotAmber {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ffd480;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dotGreen {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #5cd65c;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  align-self: center;
}

.squareRed {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ff3333;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.squareAmber {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #ffd480;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.squareGreen {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: #5cd65c;
  align-self: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="flexBox">
          West Europe
          <span class="squareGreen" />
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="flexBox">
          North Europe
          <span class="squareRed" />
        </div>
      </th>

      <th>
        <div class="flexBox">
          East Europe
          <span class="squareAmber" />
        </div>
      </th>

      <th>
        <div class="flexBox">
          East US-2
          <span class="squareGreen" />
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      IoT Hub
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      IoT Hub
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      IoT Hub
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      IoT Hub
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      TimeSeries Insights
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      TimeSeries Insights
      <span class="dotRed" />
    </td>
    <td>
      TimeSeries Insights
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      TimeSeries Insights
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Service Bus
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Service Bus
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Service Bus
      <span class="dotAmber" />
    </td>
    <td>
      Service Bus
      <span class="dotGreen" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```